# Notepad++ keyboard shortcut to toggle "Find Result" window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle "Find Result" windows? Or can this be configured in the **Shortcut Mapper**? I seem cannot find the setting.

Answer (score 22):

Once in a while I could not find the "Search Results" window.  I hit F7 to show it but no luck, and I know I have not undocked the windows as a separate window either.  Then, someone suggested that I might have minimize it all the way down to the status bar.  So, if you have done that by accident:

1. mouse over to the top section of the status bar
2. the cursor will change to the vertical resize shape
3. hold it using the left mouse click, and drag it upward to reveal the missing search result window

Also note that the "Search Results" window can be docked to left, right, or top of the window too.  Try moving the cursor near those sides if the vertical resize shape does not appear when mousing over top section of the status bar.  Once the vertical status bar appears, just left mouse click, and drag inward toward the center of the window to reveal the missing search result window.

I hope this suggestion helps some other people who would be frustrated as I was.

Comment: This is funny... it totally works!

Answer (score 14):

I have only half an answer - which you probably already know ...

<kbd>F7</kbd> Shows the "Search Results" window, and allows you to jump from it to the editing section and back to it. But I couldn't find a way to hide/close it.

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible to do it directly in `Notepad++`, but it is possible using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com). The following script will convert `F7` from an open-only shortcut to a toggle; it opens it if it isn't already open, and closes it if it is.

Here is the script:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Ed Cottrell's AutoHotKey script for toggling the "Find Results" pane/window in Notepad++
; Released under the MIT License (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
; Version: 1.1
; Release Date: January 15, 2014
; Released on Superuser.com: http://superuser.com/questions/700357/create-a-hotkey-keyboard-shortcut-to-close-the-notepad-find-results-window
; Also released at www.edcottrell.com/2014/01/11/toggle-find-results-window-notepad-hotkey/
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Turn F7 into a toggle for the Notepad++ search results window; currently it shows it, but doesn't hide it.
; The $ prevents this from firing itself
*$F7::
Open := 0
SetTitleMatchMode 2  ; AHK doesn't seem to recognize the window title otherwise
; See if Notepad++ is the active window or if the undocked results window (ahk_class #32770) is the active window
If WinActive("Notepad++")
{
    ; If the results pane is open, close it
    ; Button1 is the class name for the title bar and close button of the results pane when docked
    ControlGet, OutputVar, Visible,, Button1, Notepad++
    if ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        If OutputVar > 0
        {
            ; Found it docked
            Open := 1
            ; Get the size and coordinates of the title bar and button
            ControlGetPos, X, Y, Width, Height, Button1
            ; Set the coordinates of the close button
            X := Width - 9
            Y := 5
            ; Send a click
            ControlClick, Button1,,,,, NA x%X% y%Y%
        }
    }
}
; If it is undocked, use ahk_class #32770
else If WinExist("Find result ahk_class #32770")
{
    ; Found it undocked
    Open := 1
    ; Close it
    WinClose
}
; It's not open, so open it
if Open = 0
{
    SendInput {F7}
}
return
```

I hope this helps everyone else out there who loves `Notepad++`!

**Edited** to fix error in detection of undocked window.

Comment: To prevent this hijacking the F7 behaviour in all windows, put `#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad++` before the `*$F7::`

Answer (score 7):

found the answer from this page
http://forum.groovypost.com/windows-xp/lost-window-off-screen-t96201.html

- Press F7 to focus OR Open the window that's offscreen
- Press "Alt & Space" you will get options to move

In my case I close that window, & when I search doc again it showed in right corner, then I docked it back !

Comment: You forgot to add "Press M (for move)" after pressing "Alt+Space".  But got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the find results pane was merely shrunk down to nothing. Place the mouse near the bottom of window and wait to get the vertical arrow cursor, then drag up.

Comment: This is nearly the exact same answer as the one above posted in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Set View always on top, then go full screen. Press Ctrl+F and do a search. Search window should appear at some screen corner. Drag it up and make it larger. Turn off full screen (F11). To reattach the find window in main double click the find window title bar.

Comment: Full screen(F11) made a difference

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the F7 help to open the search window where all the relevant lines open in respect of your search word/statement etc.

I liked notepad++ it make easy the life of us.

Comment: It certainly works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is hidden on the bottom, move your cursor from the bottom past the bottom edge of the window and up until the cursor turns to an up-down arrow. Hold down the left mouse button and drag the top of the Search Results window up.

To close the Search Results window, select the x in the upper right corner of the Search results window.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to toggle the search results pane is a strangely missing feature.  It is even more strange because somebody has written the code to assign the proper behavior to the F7 key.  You can patch the code and compile it yourself, or you can download the binary (a bit outdated) that he has also made available.

## http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/patches/220/

If you wish to toggle the search results window in Notepad++ all you have to do is drag the 'search results window' to the extreme right end of the page and drop it there by releasing control of the mouse. I tried and it worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The question at the top happens to be linked from another closed discussion considered to be a duplicate. The question in that other discussion was:
"How to unhide notepad++ search-result window?"

I also came across this irritating problem, and sadly none of the answers here helped me. But I managed to find yet another answer somewhere else, and it DID solve my problem. It may be found here:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/a-quick-question-about-finding-my-find-all-in-notepad.

And just in case it somehow gets deleted, here's the solution:

1. Press <kbd>F11</kbd> for full-screen mode OR click on View > Toggle Full Screen Mode.
2. A tab for the minimized "finds" pane should appear on the Taskbar awaiting re-maximization.
3. Maximize it, dock it, and try to never hide it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting 'View' then select 'Always on top' The search bar will appear on your monitor (if like mine, if was at the bottom of the screen as i almost missed it).Then drag the 'Find' window back onto Notepad ++ and dock it in the program where you like.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.