# Notepad++ Gurus: how to unhide notepad++ search-result window

Tags: windows, notepad++

When you use find-all and find-in-files in Notepad++ a search-result window appears below the screen.
On my system this window have been hidden (possible I have dragged it to minimize) and it cannot be unhide.

I have tried to drag all bars in notepad++ window; but nothing was able to unhide it.
The window is still there - somewhere in dark - and if I press <kbd>F7</kbd> and enter, the first search result will be open. but the search-result window is still hidden.

Comment: A simple solution is to delete folder `%APPDATA%/Notepad++` and re-open Notepad++. It will start fresh (and somehow keep the plugins you installed but not their settings).

Comment: I had to only delete `config.xml`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My search window was un-docked and it had went out of the screen for some reason I didn't get.

This time I searched for a word, and chose **Search All Opened Documents**', then I pressed <kbd>F7</kbd> so the cursor goes to the 'Search Window'.

Then I used the old <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> to move that window.
And it worked! it was somewhere in the middle of a non-existent screen.

Comment: How do you move after pressing `Alt+Space, M` ?

Comment: using arrow keys (right - left, up, down).

Comment: In Windows 10, with monitors set to different scaling (e.g. one has high pixel density), it may help to make sure Notepad++ is on the FIRST monitor. Notepad++ seems to be confused by multi-monitor scaling. Worst case, detach other monitors and sign out/back in, then re-open Notepad++, then do the trick in this answer to get hold of the lost window.

Answer (score 5):

As posted on a previous answer on a relevant question, have you tried this solution?

1. Mouse over to the top section of the status bar
2. The cursor will change to the vertical resize shape
3. Hold it using the left mouse click, and drag it upward to reveal the missing search result window

Comment: Can you provide a link to the relevent question please?

Comment: [here](http://superuser.com/questions/405192/notepad-keyboard-shortcut-to-toggle-find-result-window) you go ! :)

Comment: no, that was not possible.but the problem was something else.

Comment: Faced the same issue and this answer solved it for me.